# How to show that these two summations are equal

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} (n!-\frac{n!}{(n-k)!})\qquad (1)$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{k!}(n-k)(k-1)\qquad (2)$$
I've got these summations as a solutions of a combinatorial problem. But I have no idea how to prove equality of them.

Comment: The first sum can be simplified to $$n n!-e \Gamma (n+1,1)+1$$

Answer (score 2):

Swap the order of summation in the first sum, so that it becomes 
$$ n! \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{k!-1}{k!} $$
Now cancel $n!$, so that you need to show
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{k!-1}{k!} = \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{(n-k)(k-1)}{k!}.$$
Observe that 
$$ \frac{ (n-k)(k-1)}{k!} +  ((k-1)!-1) \frac{n-k}{(k-1)!} = \frac{k!-1}{k!} + (k!-1)\frac{n-(k+1)}{k!}.$$
Using this to substitute for $(n-k)(k-1)/k!$ in the second sum gives you the result, because the new terms telescope.